# Booting Ubuntu 12.04 from a USB fails on my VAIO

Tags: boot, usb, vaio

I have already set everything up in BIOS to look for the USB first. However, when it tries to use the USB, the VAIO symbol just keeps appearing and dissappearing. So far I have tried two different versions of Ubuntu and two different USB key creators. Does anyone know how I can get it to boot? Thanks.

Comment: On my ASUS I had to change HDD priorities to enable boot from USB. Is it possible to be something similar?

Comment: Possibly. Where do I find the HDD priorities?

Comment: For me it's just below *Boot Priorities*, in the Boot portion of BIOS settings, .

Comment: Couldn't find it there... It might be worth mentioning that I am currently running Windows 8.

Comment: So it’s better you couldn't boot! I have ever installed 12.04.1 alongside Windows 8, but it didn't boot at the startup because of safe boot. You should install 12.10.

Answer (score 1):

on most vaios **you need to tap the F11** key when you **first start** your vaio, this will boot from a USB device.